# gmsh: command not found

Tags: python, cluster-computing

I am using the university's clusters to run few computations using gmsh and getdp. I wrote a python script to automate the simulations. However, I keep getting the following error:
`-bash: gmsh: command not found`
even though I have added the gmsh executable to the folder.
Any ideas of how can I deal with this? I've checked few gmsh forums where the commands proposed require  sudo rights.

Comment: is it in the path variables?

Comment: I am really new to this, I don't know how to add it to the path variables especially in a cluster (linux) I've always used windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the path variables are not added for `gmsh`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/gmsh"
```